# MultiaxisArrangement Functionality in v13.0

Tags: plotting

At long last, built-in multiple axes plots are included in version 13.

However, the current implementation seems a little half-baked. `MultiaxisArrangement` only seems to work in `ListPlot` and related, but not `Plot`, `DateListPlot`, etc. It also seems to ignore `PlotRange` and doesn't support multiple `ScalingFunctions`.

Plot Range example (blue data is cut off):

```
ListLinePlot[data, MultiaxisArrangement -> {{1}, {2}}, PlotRange -> {0, 400}]
```

[image]

Scaling example (I want the left axis Log and the right Linear, not the x-axis):

```
ListPlot[{
 Table[{x, Exp[x^-2]}, {x, 0.25, 5, 0.25}], 
 Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/100}]}, 
 MultiaxisArrangement -> {{1}, {2}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear"}]
```

[image]

I'm happy that this functionality now exists, but a little more time in the oven could have helped. Since this earned quite a few words in the Version 13 Announcement Blog, it feels like I'm missing something. Is there hidden functionality I'm not seeing?