# How to label lines and adjust ticks in `MultiaxisArrangement`?

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

I see we can make multi-axes with `MultiaxisArrangement`, but how can we adjust the ticks and how to label the lines in it or how to place plot legends of those lines?

How to label these two lines with `Hello` and `Goodbye` and make the horizontal ticks to `{one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten}`?

For example:

```
ListLinePlot[{RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10]}, 
 MultiaxisArrangement -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: `MultiaxisArrangement` is nice in principle, but it appears to be somewhat incomplete in functionality. Take a look at [How to get axes labels with MultiaxisArrangement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261425/27951) and [1 plot two different y scales](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263442/27951). Along the same lines, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260894/27951), although heavily upvoted, remained unanswered.