# How to add axes in MultiaxisArrangement?

Tags: plotting, labeling, fonts

```
Labeled[
 ListLinePlot[
  {Range[10], Prime[Range[10]], Range[10]^2}, 
  MultiaxisArrangement -> {Right -> {1, 2}, Left -> 3},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small},
  ImagePadding -> "Quality",
  Joined -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  AxesOrigin -> {1}
  ], {"Cascading steps", "Number of sectors", 
  "Shock propagation trajectory", "Recovery process", 
  "Risk of economic loss"}, All, RotateLabel -> True]
```

produces:

[image]

[These answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261435/60365) are addressing the same issue but the one I have is missing.

In the above figure, the Blue axis name "Risk of economic loss" on the right-hand side is missing. Also, the origin of the axis should start from 1 to avoid the empty space on the figure. I tried `AxisOrigin->{1}` but it does not work. The fonts used in the entire figure should be the same. Last, the colors of the axes are not really visible.

Comment: `MultiAxisArrangement` is nice in principle, but its execution is still incomplete and half-baked. For instance, it has [problems with `PlotRange` and scaling functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260894/27951), [axis labeling and formatting ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/268196/27951). It is unfortunate, because this is a significant drawback in MMA. Perhaps the [`MultipleAxesPlot` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesListPlot/) could help. It's rather disappointing though.

Comment: how about [this approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261439/125)?

Comment: try also [this answer by Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284347/125)?

Comment: @kglr: Thanks for the links. They answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

For purposes of completeness, I post this answer (due to kglr and Lukas Lang):

```
data1 = Range\[10\];
data2 = Prime\[Range\[10\]\];
data3 = Range\[10\]^2;

ResourceFunction\["CombinePlots"\]\[
 ListLogLinearPlot\[
  data1,
  PlotRange -> {0, 30},
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 450,
  FrameLabel -> {"Cascading steps", "Number of sectors"},
  FrameStyle -> Blue,
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 12},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled\[0.03\]}
  \],
 ListLogLinearPlot\[
  data2,
  PlotRange -> {0, 300},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Cascading steps", "Recovery process"},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled\[0.03\]},
  FrameStyle -> Darker@Green,
  PlotStyle -> Darker@Green,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled\[0.03\]}
  \],
 ListLogLinearPlot\[
  data3,
  PlotRange -> {-200, 200},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Cascading steps", "Risk of economic loss"},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled\[0.03\]},
  FrameStyle -> Orange,
  PlotStyle -> Orange,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled\[0.03\]}\],
 "AxesSides" -> {Left, Right, Right -> 2}
 \]]
```

[image]

Comment: Although the code I gave above satisfies my need, I am not really happy about the code itself because there are many repetitions that make the code much longer than what `MultiaxisArrangement` promises to provide. `MultiaxisArrangement` is attractive because its is very short and flexible.